# Этимология слова "тысяча"

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение существительного "тысяча"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Это слово исконно славянское** и представлено в других языках так: укр. *ти́сяча*, др.-русск. *тысяча*, русск.-цслав. *тысѫща, тысѧща*, ст.-слав. *тысѩшти, тысѫшти*, болг. *ти́сеща*, сербохорв. диал. *ти̏суħа*, словен. *tisȯ́ča*, чеш., слвц., *tisíc*, польск. *tysiąc*, в.-луж. *tуsас*.

Можно попытаться восстановить общеславянскую форму **tysetja (*тысęтйа)*, которая, вероятно, восходит к индоевропейскому сложению **tūs-* «толстое» и **kɨ̥̄tom* «сто», то есть первоначально «большая сотня». Так, кстати, «тысяча» оказывается родственно слову «тыл» (задняя сторона чего-либо).

*(Использованы данные "Этимологического словаря русского языка" М. Фасмера.)*